# WiX Light can't find a downloaded github actions artifact

Tags: github, msbuild, wix

In one step of a github actions job, I download an artifact that was uploaded in a previous job. I see these messages in the workflow output:

```
Artifact Executable_file was downloaded to D:\a\pcm_pcmplatinum_u\pcm_pcmplatinum_u\PCMateSetup\PCMPLUS.exe

Artifact download has finished successfully
```

In a subsequent step of the same job, I run msbuild on a *.wixproj file. Candle runs without error, but Light fails with this error:

```
error LGHT0103: The system cannot find the file 'D:\a\pcm_pcmplatinum_u\pcm_pcmplatinum_u\PCMateSetup\.\PCMPLUS.exe'.
```

Here are the relevant sections of the workflow .yml file:

```
- name: Download executable file
  uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
  with:
    name: Executable_file
    path: ./PCMateSetup/PCMPLUS.exe

- name: Build PCMateSetup
  run: |
    msbuild /m /p:MajorVer="${{env.majVer}}" /p:MinorVer="${{env.minVer}}" /p:BuildVer="${{env.bldVer}}" /p:ProtoVer="0" /p:GithubBld="true" /p:Configuration=${{env.BUILD_CONFIGURATION}} /v:n ${{env.SOLUTION_FILE_PATH}}\PCMateSetup\PCMateSetup.wixproj
```

From the .wxs files:

```
<?define PCMPlus.TargetDir="$(var.ProjectDir)." ?>

<File Id="file.instDir.PCMPLUSExecutable" Vital="yes" Source="$(var.PCMPlus.TargetDir)\PCMPLUS.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
```

And also from the output messages:

```
ProjectDir: D:\a\pcm_pcmplatinum_u\pcm_pcmplatinum_u\PCMateSetup\
```

I see no reason why Light should be failing this way. I did try changing the WiX code to eliminate the extra backslash and period in the path to the file, but Light failed with the same error. Does anyone have any idea why Light is failing to find the file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In one path it's `PCMateSetup` and in the other path it's `PCMateSetup.`

Comment: Well you didn't actually post your WXS source so all I can tell you is the Path light says it can't find isn't the path that the artifact was copied to.

Comment: I added more info to the question and improved the formatting. Hope that helps.

Comment: Try changing <?define PCMPlus.TargetDir="$(var.ProjectDir)." ?> to <?define PCMPlus.TargetDir="$(var.ProjectDir)" ?> or get rid of the line and change Source="$(var.PCMPlus.TargetDir)\PCMPLUS.exe" to Source="$(var.ProjectDir)\PCMPLUS.exe"

Comment: Yeah, I did try removing the '.' in the TargetDir def and removing the '\' in the other .wxs file to avoid "\\" in path, but still got the same error. Will try the other change you suggested. Problem is, there are well over 100 files that would need the same change, so was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: Made the change and the result is the same except the extra period and backslash chars no longer appear in the LGHT0103 error message. Anyone have any other idea what the problem might be, or suggestions on where else I should look for help?

Comment: I had something similar, I had to set Light = -sval